# Proving $ \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x^3 - 5x + 4}{x^2 - 2} = \frac{16}{7}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

I have a proof for the limit $$ \lim_{x \to 3} \frac{x^3 - 5x + 4}{x^2 - 2} = \frac{16}{7}.$$ I am unsure about finding a constant to make the following true: $0 < |x-3| < \delta$, then $\left|f(x) - \frac{16}{7}\right| <\epsilon$. I have the needed $|x-3|$, and used the inequality to reduce to something I could work with. See the "HERE" below.

Proof:

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then there exists a $\delta > 0$ for $0 < |x - 3| < \delta$ such that $|f(x) - \frac{16}{7}| < \epsilon$. Then $|f(x) - \frac{16}{7}| < \epsilon$ iff
\begin{align*}
\left|\frac{x^3 + 5x + 4}{x^2 -2} - \frac{16}{7}\right| &= \left|\frac{7x^3 - 35x + 28 - 16x^2 + 32}{7x^2 - 14}\right| = \left|\frac{7x^3 - 16x^2 - 35x + 60}{7x^2 - 14}\right| \\
&= \left|\frac{(x-3)(7x^2 + 5x - 20)}{7x^2 - 14}\right| \\
&= |x-3|\left|\frac{7x^2 + 5x - 20}{7x^2 - 14}\right|~~~\text{HERE}\\    
&\leq |x-3|\left|\frac{7x^2 + 5x}{7x^2}\right| \\
&= |x-3|\left|1+\frac{5}{7x}\right|.
\end{align*}
We now replace the term, $|1 + \frac{5}{7x}|$, with a constant. Assume $\delta \leq 1$. Then
\begin{align*}
&|x-3| < \delta \leq 1 \Rightarrow -1 < |x-3| < 1 \Rightarrow 2 < |x| < 4 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2} > |\frac{1}{x}| > \frac{1}{4} \Rightarrow \frac{5}{14} > |\frac{5}{7x}| > \frac{5}{28} \\
& \Rightarrow 1 + \frac{5}{14} > |1 + \frac{5}{7x}| > 1 + \frac{5}{28} \\
& \Rightarrow \frac{38}{28} > |1 + \frac{5}{7x}| > \frac{33}{28}.
\end{align*}

It follows that $|x+3||1 + \frac{5}{7x}| < |x+3|\frac{38}{28} < \epsilon$ iff $|x+3| < \frac{28}{38}\epsilon$. Now to guarantee our assumptions made on $\delta$, choose $\delta = \min\left\{1, \frac{28}{38}\epsilon\right\}$. Therefore, if $0 < |x - 3| < \delta$, then $$\left|f(x) - \frac{16}{7}\right| < \epsilon$$

Comment: You can mimic the proof for "Quotient of two continuous function is continuous", or prove that as a lemma.

Comment: @Henry W. So, by proving that $x^3 - 5x + 4$ and $x^2 - 2$ are continuous (which they are since polynomials) I can say that the quotient is also continuous on all values except where the denominator is 0?

Comment: Yes. Technically this follows from the continuity of division.

Comment: @HenryW. Maybe one needs to be carefull in concluding continuity, because at $x=\sqrt{2}$ the fraction is not conitinuous. Continuity at the given point $x=3$ is true though.

Comment: @Tomas This can be avoided by restricting the domain of the denominator.

Comment: @HenryW. Indeed.